# How to search documents in share point using share point API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I need to develop application in mvc, to search documents (doc,pdf,txt etc..) in share points using share point API and display in UI as same as Google search. How i can do it C#.

Comment: Please add any attempt you have made at creating a solution, then we may be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks or response.Team wants to use share point 2016 API. How can i do it ..

Comment: Until you provide a coding attempt of your own, you are likely to get little help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [KeywordQuery](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/query-search-sharepoint-2013-client-object-model) to search based on SharePoint search service.

Demo search query

```
(FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:pdf) (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem"){search text}
```

Comment: Thanks or response.
I did this one but management is asking share point 2016 API. How can i do it  How can i achieve it..